# How to Select By Location from Polygons on ArcGIS Desktop but incorporate the attributes from the Polygons used to select the other layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-location

I am working with two datasets right now. The first dataset is the provincial wetland layer and the second dataset is rare species data. I buffered the species data by 100 m.

What I want is all wetlands that have rare species close (within) 100 m of the data point. I used the "select by Location" tool and this works great for selecting all the wetlands that touch or overlap with the species occurrence polygon. This is all great but is there a way to incorporate the attribute data of the rare species data into the select wetland? I am envisioning an output that has all wetlands with rare species occurrences and in the attributes of the wetland layer it will have the name of the rare species found in the wetland. Right now my output is just selected wetlands but it gives you no context on why they were selected.

Comment: Intersect wetlands with birds buffers. Do pivot table with wetland id being row name and bird names as columns name, field to summarize - any. You can join (field) pivot table to wetlands polygons. You might end up with too many columns if there are many bird species around wetlands.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Join Attributes by Location on QGIS and this gives me exactly what I wanted. Not sure how to do it on ArcGIS.